# How to concatenate a string with dynamic number or characters and use it in WHERE and JOIN clauses in MS Access db

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I was asked to add a query in MS Access Db. I thought this should have been easy but, the code I would use in SQL Server does not work.

There are two tables with common field. The problem is that in one table this field is always 8 characters length with leading 0's (number with leading 0's) and in another just a number with no leading 0's. Both fields data types Short Text.

So, in table1 field DIS would be 00000003 and in table2 field DIS would be 3 or, 00000022 and 22 referring to the same value.

So, to run a WHERE or JOIN in MS SQL Server I could do something like this

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2
FROM t1
WHERE t1.DIS = Replicate('0', 8-Len(t1.DIS)) + '3'

OR

SELECT t1.field1, t2.field1
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.DIS = Replicate('0', 8-Len(t2.DIS) +'22'
```

I tried to do something like this in MS Access and I am getting data mismatched error.

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.DIS = String(8 - LEN(t1.DIS),'0') & '3';
```

"Data type mismatched in criteria expression" is the expression "LEN(t1.DIS)". I tried to convert it to integer, I think CInt and few other methods but, nothing seem to work. If I replace the expression with a number and do following it works fine

```
String(8 - 1,'0') & '3'
```

Thank you

Comment: access or sql server?

Comment: @Jaime Drq. Access

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to compare the values as integers:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t2.field1
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON CINT(t1.DIS) = CINT(t2.DIS)
```

For larger numbers, you can use `CDEC()`:

```
     ON CDEC(t1.DIS) = CDEC(t2.DIS)
```